# Как показывать контент согласно параметру в URL?

Tags: php, url

Я хотел сделать динамический раздел статей, у меня есть вывод заголовка и описания на основную страницу. Всё в комплекте работает вот по следующему коду:

```
<?php
  $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  echo '<div class="d-flex page-card card"><div class="title">' .$row['title']. '</div><br><div class="description">'.$row['description'].'</div>';
                                        
?>
<br>
<a href="/page?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">Подробнее</a>
</div>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Я хотел бы, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Подробнее" выводился контент по параметру, например: page?id=1 выведет текст из БД записи с ID 1, page?id=2 выведет текст с ID 2 и так далее.

Но пока что не догоняю, как такое реализовать.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Озвученная вами задача предполагает, что по клику на "Подробнее", происходит дополнительное обращение к вашему серверу, откуда и подтягивается контент. Согласно этого у пользователя (на клиентской стороне) должен быть javasctipt на странице, который и будет отправлять этот запрос к серверу. На сервере, в свою очередь, должен ожидаться такой запрос по ID и отправляться соответствующий ответ.

Comment: P.S. вышеозвученное мной предполагало, что текст открывается на той же странице, aka под спойлером. Если же по клику открывается новая страница, то в вашем PHP нужен ещё один блок с ожиданием запроса и параметром в $_GET.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, спасибо! Разобрался, действительно работает.